# Can't upload file from php to nodejs

Tags: php, node.js, curl

I have two parts of my project. The first one is PHP part, that takes file and send it to the second part. Here is my code:

```
    $file = fopen('file.wav', 'r');
    $size = filesize('file.wav');
    $ex_id = getExternalId();
    $apiurl = 'http://url.to.the.second.part/?id='.$ex_id.'&oneway=true';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiurl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, $size);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($file);
    //apply logic to $result
    exit(0);
```

The second part is API part on nodejs. I can handle requests, and get `id` parameter from query, but `req.body` is undefined:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.put('api.url', (req, res) => {
   const externalId = req.query.id;
   //do some stuff here...

   //and here i'm expecting uploaded file
   //but i got nothing here
   const file = req.body;

   //other logic here...
   res.status(200).send(result);
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: you need to use a library to process file on the node server, (it's then in `req.file`, not body), see here: [Express multer middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html). and then see here: [PHP cURL Upload File To Node JS Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62354473/php-curl-upload-file-to-node-js-server)

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the file using `fopen` fun which returns file pointer resource. You need to get the contents of the file and for that you can use `file_get_contents` function and then pass the file contents in the request parameter.

```
$file = file_get_contents('file.wav');
```